# how do I show a webpage in a modal popup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm having surprisingly bad luck finding a decent resource for this. But What I'm doing is creating a list of tickets using a ListView. One of the controls in the item template is a link button that shows the header of the ticket. When the user clicks the link button, I want to open a modal window that shows the ticket in readable format. To get the ticket, I'll be passing that page a variable and it'll do the rest; nothing complicated. The page will have 3 buttons and the windows needs to close when you click one of them.

Now, I figured out how to use the ModalPopupExtender from the Ajax tookit more or less. You create the panel in it's own div which stays hidden. I created a click event that basically uses a webclient to download the html from the page and insert it into that div's innerHtml. This seems to work the first time. But as soon as you click a different link, the page pukes and says something about it being in an illegal state.

I'm not sure if I'm going about this wrong, and I can't find any decent examples of how to do this. Well there's one, but the english is hard to understand and it's in VB instead of C#. Any help?

Comment: Difficult to answer without the exact error message or code, but it sounds like you might be making changes the page's viewstate at the wrong point in the page's life cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
  <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div> 
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager> 

        <br /> 

<asp:ModalPopupExtender 
DropShadow="true" 
OkControlID="btnOk" 
CancelControlID="btnClose" 
runat="server" 
PopupControlID="Panel1" 
id="ModalPopupExtender1" 
TargetControlID="Button1" /> 


<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style="display:none;"> 
This is basic modal popup. 
<br /><br /> 
<asp:Button ID="btnOk" runat="server" Text="Ok" /> 
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close Me" /> 
  <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe> 

</asp:Panel> 




<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="First Modal Popup" /> 


    </div> 
    </form>

    Try this it should work.
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid iframes, but this will do